# React-Navigation jumpToIndex undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am getting this error . I am trying to make user press on tabbar and the content scrolls to the top but I am getting jumpToIndex is not a function

This is my code:

```
const NavigationBar = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeNav, navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: 'Home',
            tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {
                console.log('onPress:', scene.route);
                jumpToIndex(scene.index);
            },
        }),
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your active version of react-navigation, `jumpToIndex` method may be depreciated,
You can visit the documentation here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabpress for how to scroll to top after the tab is focused.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using react native navigation v4, but your code is deprecated

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/material-bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbaronpress

```
const NavigationBar = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeNav, navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: 'Home',
            tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}) => {
               // your logic
            },
        }),
    }
})
```